# Facebook Auth on iOS

Tags: iphone, facebook, single-sign-on

iOS beginner here. I am implementing SSO in my iOS app. I've created a Facebook object with

```
Facebook* facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:appId];
[facebook authorize:permissions delegate:self];
```

How do I stay logged in after the user closes the app? Do I persist this facebook object in Core Data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use [`NSUserDefaults`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/UserDefaults/Tasks/UsingDefaults.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000719-BAJFBAAH), which is what I have used in the past. You only need to persist the `expirationDate` and `accessToken`. Once you restore those into the Facebook object on launch, you can call `isSessionValid` to determine that validity of both those properties.